# How to properly close MariaDB and MySQL connections when using both connectors within a project

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb

I am currently working on a project in which there are approximately 100 functions that are responsible for making raw queries to the
DB. Depending on whether the code is on the local server or on the staging server, one connector or the other (MySQL or MariaDB) will be used.

To do this, I have implemented the `get_cursor()` function that returns the cursor for each case.

The point is that, as far as I know, this is not a good practice since I have to close the connections after the queries are made.

```
def get_cursor():
        #MariaDB cursor for Django
    if 'local' == settings.DJANGO_HOST:
        conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="user",
        password="password",
        host="localhost",
        database="db-dummy")
        return conn.cursor(named_tuple=True)
    else:
        #Default Django MySQL cursor
        return connection.cursor()  

#MariaDB connector
def get_some_data_mariadb(record_id):
    results = []
    cursor  = get_cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT blabla some query")
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        return results
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


#MySQL connector
def get_some_data_mysql(record_id):
    results = []
    cursor  = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT blablabla")
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    results = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    return results
```

The code for now works, but if I do a lot of queries I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /selected-interpretation/
Too many connections
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/selected-interpretation/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
Too many connections
Exception Location: /Users/user/Developer/project/subfolder/db.py in get_cursor, line 22
Python Executable:  /Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['/Users/user/Developer/project',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 14 Jun 2021 16:13:30 +0900
```

Is there a way I can close the connections outside of `get_cursor()`?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/)? Not to mention why don't you simply use different setting files depending on local / staging server?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for the insights, yeah I checked the official docs but since I'm using a custom connector for MariaDB there is not much info about it. I use different settings depending on the local / staging server. I just want to know how to close properly the connections with the above logic. Should I just send also the connection in the return of get_cursor?

Answer (score 0):

In your program

- Connect *only* once to each of the two servers.  (This may be the *real* problem.)
- Hang on to that "connection" so you can...
- disconnect at *the end* of the program.